# How to generate a result list from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I need to generate a list from pandas DataFrame . I am able to print the result,but  i don't know how to convert it to the list format.The code i used to print the result(without converting to list) is

```
df=pandas.DataFrame(processed_data_format, columns=["file_name", "innings", "over","ball", "individual ball", "runs","batsman", "wicket_status","bowler_name","fielder_name"])**  
  #processed_data_format is the list passing to the DataFrame   
t = df.groupby(['batsman','over'])['runs','ball'].sum()
print t
```

i am getting the result like

```
Sangakara 1   10   5

          2    0   2

          3    3   1


    sewag 1    2   1

          2    1   1
```

I would like to convert this data into list format like

***[ [sangakara,1,10,5],[sangakara,2,0,2],[sangakara,3,3,1],[sewag,1,2,1][sewag,2,1,1] ]***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [2, 3, 4, 5]})

>>> list(df.to_records())

 [(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```

This will make a list of tuples. Converting this to a list of lists (if you really need this at all), is easy.

Comment: Thank you .It works, How to convert it to List of lists??

Comment: @EdwinBaby See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831830/convert-a-list-of-tuples-to-a-list-of-lists).

Comment: The answer is really helpful for me, Since i am new to StackOverflow i did'nt know about the things .So, thanks for point out the things