# How to merge two lists into a list of multiple lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given two lists lst1 and lst2:

```
lst1 = ['a']
lst2 = [['b'],
        ['b', 'c'],
        ['b', 'c', 'd']]
```

I'd like to merge them into a list of multiple lists with a desired output like this:

```
desiredList = [['a', ['b']],
              ['a', ['b', 'c']],
              ['a', ['b', 'c', 'd']]]
```

Here is one of my attempts that comes close using `lst1 + lst2` and `list.append()`:

```
lst3 = []
for elem in lst2:
    new1 = lst1
    new2 = elem
    theNew = new1 + new2
    lst3.append(theNew)

print(lst3)

#Output:
#[['a', 'b'],
#['a', 'b', 'c'],
#['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Expanding on this, I thought another variation with `theNew = new1.append(new2)`would do the trick. But no:

```
lst3 = []
for elem in lst2:
    new1 = lst1
    new2 = elem
    #print(new1 + new2)
    #theNew = new1 + new2
    theNew = new1.append(new2)

    lst3.append(theNew)
print(lst3)

# Output:
[None, None, None]
```

And you'll get the same result with `extend`.

I guess this should be really easy, but I'm at a loss.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: `list.append()` is in-place and `return`s `None` so never assign to it with `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve your desired output with `itertools.zip_longest` with a `fillvalue`:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> list(zip_longest(lst1, lst2, fillvalue=lst1[0]))
[('a', ['b']), ('a', ['b', 'c']), ('a', ['b', 'c', 'd'])]
```

Or if you need a list of lists:

```
>>> [list(item) for item in zip_longest(lst1, lst2, fillvalue=lst1[0])]
[['a', ['b']], ['a', ['b', 'c']], ['a', ['b', 'c', 'd']]]
```

Note this assumes that `lst1` always contains a single element as in your example.

Comment: Or just: `[[*lst1, other] for other in lst2]`

Comment: @Jon Clements. As far as I can tell, this has to be the most elegant solution. Would you like to write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use use append, but you need to create new copy of the lst1:

```
lst3 = []
for elem in lst2:
    theNew = lst1[:]
    theNew.append(new2)
    lst3.append(theNew)
print(lst3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product

list(product(lst1,lst2))
>>>[('a', ['b']), ('a', ['b', 'c']), ('a', ['b', 'c', 'd'])]

[lst1 + [new] for new in lst2]
>>>[['a', ['b']], ['a', ['b', 'c']], ['a', ['b', 'c', 'd']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**This might help**

```
desiredlist = list(map(lambda y:[lst1,y],lst2))
```