# Convert Number of tuples to List of List in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
postgreSQL_select_Query = "select Query"

        cur.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)

        records = cur.fetchall() 
        print("Selecting rows ",records)
        print("Print each row and it's columns values")
        for row in records:
             print(row)
```

in the above code print row is given below.

```
('1970-01-01', '1')
('2019-01-01', '2')
('2019-01-12', '3')
('2019-01-19', '2')
('2019-02-16', '1')
('2019-02-19', '1')
('2019-02-22', '1')
('2019-02-24', '1')
('2019-02-25', '1')
('2019-02-26', '1')
('2019-03-02', '1')
('2019-03-05', '1')
('2019-03-07', '1')
('2019-03-08', '1')
('2019-03-10', '1')
('2019-03-13', '2')
('2019-03-16', '1')
```

How to convert above result to list of list in python 
The assumed result is `list=[['1970-01-01', '1'],['1970-01-01', '1']]`

Comment: what is the type of the output? ist it list or a tuple too?

Comment: What is wrong with tuples? If you must convert it, you can use `my_lists = list(map(list, my_tuples))`.

Comment: Very basic problem, already answered hundreds of times: [convert-a-list-of-tuples-to-a-list-of-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831830/convert-a-list-of-tuples-to-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: @selcuk this is the out put get  to me <map object at 0x7f72bae57a90>
<map object at 0x7f72bae57fd0>
<map object at 0x7f72bae57a90>
<map object at 0x7f72bae57fd0>
<map object at 0x7f72bae57a90>

Comment: Why are you changing question several times

Comment: This is my first question

Comment: I think i already explained the answer

Answer (score -1):

`list comprehension` is what i am going to use

```
postgreSQL_select_Query = "select Query"
cur.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
records = cur.fetchall() 
output = [list(row) for row in records]
```

`output` is what you need here i guess

Comment: ... only if he hast a tuple of tuples as input ... and the question is so basic and so often answered it is a dupe.

Comment: That's why i created the input in my answer. Yes, it seems possible duplicate

Comment: what are you saying here? tuple of tuples in I/P and list of list is O/P here i guess

Comment: check for [list(i) for i in t] line