# Convert list of tuples to list Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

How do I convert

```
[('Paulo Coelho', 74, 'brasileño'), ('Ziraldo', 89, 'brasileño')]
```

to

```
[['Paulo Coelho', 74, 'brasileño'], ['Ziraldo', 89, 'brasileño']]
```

any method for different sizes of tuples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a list of tuples to a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831830/convert-a-list-of-tuples-to-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `list()` and list comprehension.

```
>>> l = [('Paulo Coelho', 74, 'brasileño'), ('Ziraldo', 89, 'brasileño')]
>>> c = [list(t) for t in l]
>>> c
[['Paulo Coelho', 74, 'brasileño'], ['Ziraldo', 89, 'brasileño']]
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is loop through the list and convert every element from a tuple to a list using `list()`

```
for i in range(len(lis)):
    lis[i] = list(lis[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

`list()` function will convert tuple into list. To convert all tuples in array you have to traverse.

```
arr = [('Paulo Coelho', 74, 'brasileño'), ('Ziraldo', 89, 'brasileño')]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i] = list(arr[i])
```

Comment: There's indenation error in your code. Please correct it